# How to table ParametricPlot with parametric value

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, list-manipulation, parametric-functions

I can plot this code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
m = 2; a = 0;
r = 0.9;
timelimit = 35;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{m x''[t] + x'[t] == 
     Cos[r t - x[t]], x[0] == a, 
    x'[0] == r - v}, x, {t, 0, timelimit}, {v}];
Plot[Evaluate@Table[{x[v][t] /. s, v}, {v, -8, 2, 1}], {t, 0, 
  timelimit}]
```

[image]

But If I want to parametric, using the similar structure, like this

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
m = 2; a = 0;
r = 0.9;
timelimit = 35;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{m x''[t] + x'[t] == Cos[r t - x[t]], x[0] == a, x'[0] == r - v}, x, {t, 0, timelimit}, {v}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[{{r t - x[v][t], r - x[v][t]} /. s, v}, {v, -8, 2, 1}], {t, 0, timelimit}]
```

I can't get the output.

How can I get the Table ParametricPlot?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: ``ParametricPlot`` is for 2-dimensional curves, so it needs two values. You are providing three instead: ``{{r t - x[v][t], r - x[v][t]} /. s, v}``. Use this: ``{r t - x[v][t], r - x[v][t]} /. s`` or use ``ParametricPlot3D`` if you want 3-dimensional curves.

Comment: v is the parameter. There still are two values? r t - x[v][t] and r - x[v][t]

Comment: Yes, as I have said, use: ``ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[{r t - x[v][t], r - x[v][t]} /. s, {v, -8, 2, 1}], {t, 0, timelimit}]``.

Comment: can you get the result using it? In the previous example of plot, we need to add ,v after /.s ```Plot[Evaluate@Table[{x[v][t] /. s, v}, {v, -8, 2, 1}], {t, 0, 
  timelimit}]```

Comment: Yes, I get a plot, you don't? It should work. But perhaps this is not the plot you actually want.

Comment: Oh, I get the new output. Thanks ! I will check the output. I think it solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned already in the comments, `ParametricPlot` is used for 2-dimensional curves, so you need to provide values in the form $\{f_x, f_y\}$:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
m = 2; a = 0;
r = 0.9;
timelimit = 35;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{m x''[t] + x'[t] == Cos[r t - x[t]], x[0] == a,
     x'[0] == r - v}, x, {t, 0, timelimit}, v];
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[{r t - x[v][t], r - x[v][t]} /. s, {v, -8, 2, 1}], {t, 0, timelimit}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Should you want to have the parameter $v$ also be used as an axis, you have to use `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate@Table[{r t - x[v][t], r - x[v][t], v} /. s, {v, -8, 2, 1}], {t, 0, timelimit}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]